# Extract Words by Comma in python

Tags: python, extract

Hey I want to code a extractor :

for example

```py
varall = "hello:my:whats:up"
```

then I want 4 differents ouput for example:

```
var1 = hello

var2 = my

var3 = whats

var4 = up
```

So I want from varall convert these 4 words into 4 differnte variables

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried? have you looked into the `str.split` method?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use the split() method:

```py
varall = "hello:my:whats:up"
varlst = varall.split(':') #splits string at the character ':'
for var in varlst:
    print(var)
```

Comment: yes Thanks thats acutally very good, how can I get it into 4 different varibales ?

Comment: If you already know the no. of variables that will be in the string, you could use sth. like: `var1 = varlst[0]; var2 = varlst[1]`... and so on. OR you could use a dictionary.

Comment: @maxowi if it helped then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use split function to achieve that.

```
txt = "hello:my:whats:up"
x = txt.split(":")
print(x)
   
#Output - ['hello', 'my', 'whats', 'up']
```

Comment: yes Thanks thats acutally very good, how can I get it into 4 different varibales ?

Answer (score 0):

```
varall = "hello:my:whats:up"
var1,var2,var3,var4=varall.split (":")
print (var1,var2,var3,var4)
```

Try This ..it will create list of strings and then store them in var1,var2,var3,var4...make sure you have only 4 words separated by ":"..